# Davinci Resolve Fusion equivalent to color-page 3D key qualifiers?

Tags: davinci-resolve

Davinci Resolve 17's Color page has a "Qualifier" tab; while the default mode is HSL, the most powerful is the 3D keyer, which has the ability to build a matte with subsets of the possible chroma and luma values (selected by drawing over regions of a frame that contains the desired color, by default working in YUV).

Is any equivalent available for use in the Fusion tab?

There are certainly tools available in the Fusion tab for RGB regions; but the 3D qualifier is considerably more powerful.